# How to use a function from opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505270/how-to-use-mikolajczyks-evaluation-framework-for-feature-detectors-descriptors) post and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36199635/how-does-the-conversion-of-an-opencv-keypoint-to-an-elliptickeypoint-work) post, I want to convert detected keypoints to elliptic keypoints by modifying [this](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/xfeatures2d/samples/surf_matcher.cpp) sample SURF detection and matching code from opencv library.

However, I have little knowledge on c++ syntax and am only familiar with matlab. Previous posts seem to point to using the following code from [evaluation.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/features2d/src/evaluation.cpp) of opencv library to convert them:

```
void EllipticKeyPoint::convert( const std::vector<KeyPoint>& src, std::vector<EllipticKeyPoint>& dst )
{
    if( !src.empty() )
    {
        dst.resize(src.size());
        for( size_t i = 0; i < src.size(); i++ )
        {
            float rad = src[i].size/2;
            CV_Assert( rad );
            float fac = 1.f/(rad*rad);
            dst[i] = EllipticKeyPoint( src[i].pt, Scalar(fac, 0, fac) );
        }
    }
}
```

The Keypoints seem to be generated after line 202 of sample code. So I tried the following to convert them to elliptic keypoints by adding:

- `cv::EllipticKeyPoint::convert(keypoints1, keypoints1);` after line 202 and
- `using namespace cv::xfeatures2d::EllipticKeyPoint` at the beginning of the code

but both showed errors saying:

- `name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name` and
- `namespace "cv::xfeatures2d" has no member "EllipticKeyPoint"` respectively

Which class/namespace/member should I use? How do I write the code properly so that I can use this function to convert keypoints to elliptic keypoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welk... you should show us your exact code if you want sensible answers, but...

If I'm not wrong, the message "name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name" is misleading: can be a static method name too, that is your intention.

The problem, I suppose, is another.

There are defined two `convert()` static methods in `EllipticKeyPoint`: the first one convert vectors of `KeyPoint` in vectors of `EllipticKeyPoint`; the second one convert vectors of `EllipticKeyPoint` in vectors of `KeyPoint`.

But when you call

```
cv::EllipticKeyPoint::convert(keypoints1, keypoints1);
```

you try to convert `keypoints1` to itself; so (vectors of) `KeyPoint` to `KeyPoint` or `EllipticKeyPoint` to `EllipticKeyPoint`.

And you lack this type of converter.

Your intention was the following ?

```
cv::EllipticKeyPoint::convert( _keypoints1 , keypoints1 );
```

In `calculateRepeatability()` I see

```
EllipticKeyPoint::convert( _keypoints1, keypoints1 );
EllipticKeyPoint::convert( _keypoints2, keypoints2 );
```

so be careful with underscores (`_`).

**--- EDIT 2016.06.11 ---**

If your intention is convert the vectors of `KeyPoint` in vectors of `EllipticKeyPoint, I suppose you should define, together`keypoints1`and`keypoints2`, another couple of vectors, something like

```
std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints1, keypoints2;
std::vector<EllipticKeyPoint> ellkeypoints1, ellkeypoints2;
```

and, when `keypoints1` and `keypoints2` al loaded, call `convert()`; I suppose something like

```
std::cout << "FOUND " << keypoints1.size() << " keypoints on first image" << std::endl;
std::cout << "FOUND " << keypoints2.size() << " keypoints on second image" << std::endl;

EllipticKeyPoint::convert(keypoints1, ellkeypoints1);
EllipticKeyPoint::convert(keypoints2, ellkeypoints2);

std::cout << "FOUND " << ellkeypoints1.size() << " elliptic keypoints on first image" << std::endl;
std::cout << "FOUND " << ellkeypoints2.size() << " elliptic keypoints on second image" << std::endl;
```

Comment: The exact code is the sample SURF code (3rd link from post). I was hoping to add 1 or 2 lines to it by using the readily available code in opencv library. I tried adding your 1 line of code to the sample code but it didn't work. Using this: `cv::evaluateFeatureDetector(img1.getMat(ACCESS_READ), img2.getMat(ACCESS_READ), H,);` seems to work but I don't understand what the 3rd argument and so on wants. It looks very confusing to me with all the different kinds of symbols. Could you explain what it means?

Comment: I mean symbols like "<>,&,*,and ::" and how they fit together are confusing to me since I'm not familiar with C++

Comment: @SK90 - Answer improved to explain (I hope) ho to use `convert()`; about the use of "<>,&,*,and ::", well... you can try asking about single example but it's very difficult give a general answer; C++ is a complex language and I suggest to study it with a good book or a very good tutorial

Comment: Tried the code but didn't work for me. Will post more specific question. Thanks.

Comment: It works. Copy and pasted convert function definition and related template/class/function definitions from evaluation.cpp, and your code to the sample code.